# Не открыть файл boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib

Tags: c++, boost

Подключил буст, всё ок, но потом компилятор начал выдвать ошибку:

> LNK1104 не открыть файл "boost_thread-vc141-mt-gd-x32-1_66.lib"

Я сначала думал, он имеет ввиду `libboost_thread-vc141-mt-x32-1_66.lib`, но нет. Как исправить ошибку?

Comment: может быть Вы трогали параметр MT MD  в настройках?

Comment: Вы смогли решить проблему ?